# optionals in a look around regular expressions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to figure out how to put option values in a lookaround with regular expressions.

These values should match

```
3
1000
15-20
2048-4096/100
```

This value should **not**

```
3/4
```

I want to say in regex "only match if there is a dash 4 digit number and a colon preceding the / division symbol

For example:

1. `-9999` preceding the `/` division symbol should match
2. `9999/` should not match because there is no -
3. `-/` should not match because there is no number

   `^[^0][0-9]*(-|:)?([0-9]*)?(?<=[0-9])(\/)?([0-9]*)$`

I have the look around just looking for a preceding number but if I put a `?` or `*` in it it no longer works. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Can you clarify what the intended rule is supposed to do? I'm not sure I understand the pattern in the list of valid numbers you supply.

Comment: dash = `-` , forward slash=`/`,  which one is it?

Comment: `(\d{4}-\d{4}/\d+)`

Comment: If I understand it, he want -a number, any number dash any number, four digit number dash four digit number forward slash any number. This last one can only be met (the use of forward slash it is preceded by a four digit number with a dash)

Comment: I add to the post hopefully its more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d+(?:[-:](?:\d{4}\/\d+|\d+))?$
```

If I'm understanding what you want correctly,

- \d+ Starts with some number
- (?: ...)? Followed by optional pattern which begins with a dash or colon
- \d{4}/\d+ The number in the optional group can be a 4 digit number with a slash and another number
- \d+ Or the optional group can be any number if it doesn't begin with a slash.

Comment: Although I could not understand this pattern: `[-:]` what is the purpose of `:` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos `[-:]` means match dash (`-`) or colon (`:`). So `2048:4096/123` is also valid.

Comment: That I know. I meant about the user requirements. He didn't mention it but now that you explained I read his question again and although he didn't mention it, you was really paying attention, in his pattern there is `(-|:)` :) cheers